# SELECT warehouses id on name from other table id name

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
product
```

| id | code | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | AA | product name1 |
| 21 | BB | product name2 |

```
warehouses
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | warehouses1 |
| 2 | warehouses2 |

```
warehouses_products
```

---

| id | product_id | warehouse_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 2 | 21 | 2 |

example

```
$sql = " SELECT * 
         FROM warehouses_products  
         WHERE warehouse_id = '".$_POST["warehouse_id"]."'"; 

$output .= ''.$row["product_id"].'';
```

I want to on only name, now on `product_id`

```
----------------------
|   product name1      |
|                      |
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data / desired output and description are not exactly clear, however you *seem* to describe a simple inner join:

```
select wp.Warehouse_id, p.name
from warehouses w
join warehouses_products wp on wp.warehouse_id = w.id
join products p on p.Id = wp.product_id
```

Comment: Why would you expect that? In truth for the sample data you don't need the warehouse table but the OP has provided it I can only assume it's a contrived example and in reality is required.

Comment: Idk why I thought that @Stu, I guess I'm forgetting SQL :P.  This proves you right though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f77d3/2/0